# Loading DataGrid from XML data file

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have a problem with loading data from an XML file in a WPF application.

XAML:

```
                    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[Person]}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="331" Margin="12,10,-1.774,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="834" FontSize="18" FontFamily="SimSun">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[name].Value}"  />
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[surname].Value}"  />
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Date born" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[dateBorn].Value}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

XML File:

```
<Persons> 
<Person>
<name>Test1</name> 
<surname>Test11</surname> 
<dateBorn>02.12.1990</dateBorn>
</Person>

<Person>
<name>Test2</name> 
<surname>Test22</surname> 
<dateBorn>10.12.1991</dateBorn>
</Person>

<Person>
<name>Test3</name> 
<surname>Test3</surname> 
<dateBorn>09.12.1992</dateBorn>
</Person>
```

My code:

```
        var peopleList = XElement.Load(dataBaseURL);
        dataGrid1.DataContext = peopleList;
```

I get empty cells and  I load data from `<person> </person>` tags.

Comment: Did you get any results for your `peopleList`? Is it possible that your xml file is not valid. It seems you are missing the header like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and the `</Persons>` closing tag at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your ItemsSource looks correct, so do the bindings.

Try `dataGrid1.DataContext = peopleList.Root;` ?

Answer (score 0):

The bindings should be corrected as such:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="331" Margin="12,10,-1.774,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="834" FontSize="18" FontFamily="SimSun">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding name}"  />
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding surname}"  />
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Date born" Binding="{Binding dateBorn}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```